# Angular http post on loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angular http post inside a loop using angular forEach as advised here- [Angular HTTP Get on loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064976/angular-http-get-on-loop) and [Angularjs loop trought $http.post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020360/angularjs-loop-trought-http-post) but the solution is not working in my case. The http post always returns result with respect to the last item in LifeBenefitTRAD but I want the result for each item in the loop. e.g. If I have 4 items in the list of LifeBenefitTRAD, my post method is executing 4 times but w.r.t the fourth item in the list.[image] The execution always happens with respect to last object.Please tell me what am I doing wrong here?-

```
   $scope.GenerateAllTradQuote = function () {
        var TRADPlanDetails = {};
        console.log(LifeBenefitTRAD);
        //for (var i = 0; i < LifeBenefitTRAD.length; i++) {
        LifeBenefitTRAD.forEach(function (trad) {
           TRADPlanDetails.QuoteName = "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue;
           TRADPlanDetails.LifeBenefitId = trad.LifeBenefitId;
           TRADPlanDetails.LifeBenefitValue = trad.LifeBenefitValue;

            console.log(TRADPlanDetails);

            $http({
                url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
                method: key_String_HttpPost,
               // async: true,
                params: TRADPlanDetails
            }).then(function (result) {
                $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails.TRAD_DisplayFlag = true;
                if (result.data != key_String_Zero) {

                    $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_Successful_Quote;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_failed_Quote;
                }
            });
        });
       // }
    };
```

Comment: In order for us to help we need to know exactly what's happening, why it's wrong, and what you expect or want to happen.

Comment: Looks like you are updating the same scope variable.. ? But not sure what you want to do..

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question..please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: I have already edited my question to make it clear then why is this negative vote ?

Comment: @Anilkumar I didn't downvote, but you're overwriting the same set of scope properties in every iteration. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @JLRishe I have removed the scope variables and now using a local variable, but even in this case, post method is working 3 times for the last assigned value to the variable.

Comment: @Anilkumar Thank you, but what is this code supposed to _do_? Can you explain its purpose in plain English? For example, why are you comparing `result.data` to `key_String_Zero`? What is the objective? It still seems that you are overwriting `TRAD_DisplayMsg` three times, and only the last value is going to remain.

Comment: This piece of code is used in my code for some other reason and not related to the problem. The url in the post is an action method of a controller class in asp .net MVC which will perform some operation. This action method is getting executed 4 times w.r.t the last item in the list.

Comment: @Anilkumar What observation is leading you to believe that only the last item in the list is being used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69852/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-jlrishe).

Comment: The method will do something in the back end resulting in creation of 4 pdf files. The data which I am getting in these pdf files are same and w.r.t the calculation based on 4th item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `TRADPlanDetails` variable *outside* of the `forEach` callback, which means that you are passing the same object to `$http` every time. If there is some delay before `$http` actually uses your values, then it will wind up using the same set of values for all of its requests.

Please try creating a new variable and a new object each time:

```
LifeBenefitTRAD.forEach(function (trad) {
    var planDetails = {
        QuoteName: "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue,
        LifeBenefitId: trad.LifeBenefitId,
        LifeBenefitValue: trad.LifeBenefitValue
    };

    $http({
        url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
        method: key_String_HttpPost,
        // async: true,
        params: planDetails
    })
    // ....
});
```

If maintaining the order of the original requests is important, you can do the following, but be aware that it will slow the process down because it will essentially wait for each request to finish before beginning the next one:

```
LifeBenefitTRAD.reduce(function (p) {
    var planDetails = {
        QuoteName: "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue,
        LifeBenefitId: trad.LifeBenefitId,
        LifeBenefitValue: trad.LifeBenefitValue
    };

    return p.then(function () {
        return $http({
            url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
            method: key_String_HttpPost,
            // async: true,
            params: planDetails
        });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        // handle result for current request
    });
}, $q.when());
```

The above requires using the `$q` service.

There *may* be a way to do some low-level stuff with `$http` that would allow you to initiate a new request right as the previous one was about to be sent off, but from what I can see, it doesn't provide anything that would easily facilitate that.

Comment: This seems working but not in the order the parameters are fed. Can we do anything so that post happens in the same order w.r.t the items in the loop?

Comment: How will it execute in FIFO order?

Comment: @Anilkumar The only easy solution involving `$http` that I can think of is to do the requests one at a time. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

[JLRishe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225386/379538) is part of it, but you also want to store the results differently, so you might want to consider doing something like this:

```
$scope.GenerateAllTradQuote = function () {
    // Clear out existing details
    $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails = {};

    // This is more compatible than Array.forEach()
    angular.forEach(LifeBenefitTRAD, function (trad) {
        var planDetails = {
            QuoteName: "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue,
            LifeBenefitId: trad.LifeBenefitId,
            LifeBenefitValue: trad.LifeBenefitValue
        };

        $http({
            url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
            method: key_String_HttpPost,
            params: TRADPlanDetails
        }).then(function (result) {
            planDetails.TRAD_DisplayFlag = true;

            if (result.data != key_String_Zero) {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_Successful_Quote;
            } else {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_failed_Quote;
            }

            $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails[planDetails.QuoteName] = planDetails;
        });
    });
};
```

You could alternatively use an array to store it and just push the completed `planDetails` object to it; up to you.

If you wanted to retain the order of request, you could store the LifeBenefitTRAD loop's index:

```
$scope.GenerateAllTradQuote = function () {
    // Clear out existing details
    $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails = {};

    // This is more compatible than Array.forEach()
    angular.forEach(LifeBenefitTRAD, function (trad, idx) {
        var planDetails = {
            QuoteName: "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue,
            LifeBenefitId: trad.LifeBenefitId,
            LifeBenefitValue: trad.LifeBenefitValue
        };

        $http({
            url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
            method: key_String_HttpPost,
            params: TRADPlanDetails
        }).then(function (result) {
            planDetails.TRAD_DisplayFlag = true;
            planDetails._index = idx;

            if (result.data != key_String_Zero) {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_Successful_Quote;
            } else {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_failed_Quote;
            }

            $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails[planDetails.QuoteName] = planDetails;
        });
    });
};
```

...Aaaaaand if you needed to put them into the `$scope` in an array, in order, you could do something like this:

```
$scope.GenerateAllTradQuote = function () {
    // Clear out existing details
    var TRAD_PlanDetails = [];

    // This is more compatible than Array.forEach()
    angular.forEach(LifeBenefitTRAD, function (trad, idx) {
        var planDetails = {
            QuoteName: "TradQuote_" + trad.LifeBenefitValue,
            LifeBenefitId: trad.LifeBenefitId,
            LifeBenefitValue: trad.LifeBenefitValue
        };

        $http({
            url: key_Url_GenerateTradQuote,
            method: key_String_HttpPost,
            params: TRADPlanDetails
        }).then(function (result) {
            planDetails.TRAD_DisplayFlag = true;
            planDetails._index = idx;

            if (result.data != key_String_Zero) {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_Successful_Quote;
            } else {
                planDetails.TRAD_DisplayMsg = key_Confirm_failed_Quote;
            }

            TRAD_PlanDetails.push(planDetails);

            // If at the last entry:
            if (idx >= LifeBenefitTRAD.length - 1) putOnScope();
        });
    });

    function putOnScope() {
        $scope.TRAD_PlanDetails = TRAD_PlanDetails.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a._index - b._index;
        });
    }
};
```