# $http call inside angular foreach loops before http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a list named $scope.propname which has an object named latlong so i need to find the distance of all properties from a specific location so here is what i am doing

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.propname.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.propname[i].latlong == "") {
    var pptlatlong = ("" + "," + "");
  } else {
    var pptlatlong = $scope.propname[i].latlong.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ",");
  }
  var latlongdata = {
    scoord: $scope.loclatlong,
    ecoord: pptlatlong
  }
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    data: latlongdata,
    url: $rootScope.ServiceBaseUri + 'Map/geolocation'
  }).then(function successCallback(resp) {
    $scope.latlongdist = resp.data;
  }, function errorCallback(resp) {});
  $scope.propname[i].dist = $scope.latlongdist;
}
```

So all the object named dist in the list are of same value after the entire loop ends.It should be different for all properties i think before the http response the loop continues is there way to wait till the http of each loop ends and then proceed ?

Comment: don't use a `$scope` property as a temporary variable for the calculation of your formula.

Comment: @Claies You mean the scope where i saved the response of the http action ?

Comment: don't use `$scope.latlongdist`;  If you use `$scope`, you should only attach to `$scope` properties that you actually intend to display in the HTML.  Your calculations are failing because even though there are multiple sets of coordinates, every set is sharing a single output variable.

Comment: For those who are really trying to get help of similar issue try this answer.Kind of worked in my situation by just changing the $http calling method.https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023191/3904336

Comment: as a side note, you wouldn't want every iteration of the loop to stop and wait for the `$http` response;  that's called a blocking operation, and `$http` is designed to be asynchronous, non-blocking.  If your loop stopped every iteration, then your script could freeze the UI .

Comment: @Claies the above posted link worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148126/discussion-between-melvin-and-claies).

Answer (score 0):

a better way,

```
var loclatlong = $scope.loclatlong,
    geolocUrl = $rootScope.ServiceBaseUri + 'Map/geolocation';

$scope.propname.forEach(function(prop, index) {

    if(prop.latlong === "") {
        var pptlatlong = (""+","+ "");
    } else {
        var pptlatlong = prop.latlong.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ",");
    }

    var latlongdata = {
        scoord: loclatlong,
        ecoord: pptlatlong
    };

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        data: latlongdata,
        url: geolocUrl
    })
    .then(
        function(res) {
            $scope.propname[index].dist = res.data;
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside your for-loop gets executed before the asynchronous call returns.

Just assign your values inside the `.then`, like:

```
$scope.propname[i].dist = response.data;
```

**Important:** the better approach would be to store all the promises inside an array and only use the `propname` values when all of them got resolved. That way you would ensure that you are not missing any unresolved values.

Comment: i tried assigning inside the success of $http but i got an error "dist of undefined"

Comment: You need to check why `$scope.propname[i]` is undefined. @Melvin

Comment: because it loops before the $http response and doesn't wait for it

Comment: But based on your question, `$scope.propname` array items should be instantiated before the loop, that's why you iterate till `i < $scope.propname.length`, no? If that's not the case, show me a little bit more of your code, please. @Melvin